# Cast to volatile, difference between C and C++

Tags: c++, c, casting, volatile

In C, code below compiles fine.

```
typedef struct T {
    int val;
} T;

void test(volatile T*p, T a) {
    *p = (volatile T)a;  // doesn't work for G++
    *p = a;  // doesn't work for G++
}
```

But in C++ (tested by gcc 12.2), it is illegal:

```
<source>: In function 'void test(volatile T*, T)':
<source>:29:22: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator=' (operand types are 'volatile T' and 'volatile T')
   29 |     *p = (volatile T)a;  // doesn't work for G++
      |                      ^
<source>:24:16: note: candidate: 'constexpr T& T::operator=(T&&)' (near match)
   24 | typedef struct T {
      |                ^
<source>:24:16: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
<source>:29:10: error: binding reference of type 'T&&' to 'volatile T' discards qualifiers
   29 |     *p = (volatile T)a;  // doesn't work for G++
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:24:16: note: candidate: 'constexpr T& T::operator=(const T&)' (near match)
   24 | typedef struct T {
      |                ^
<source>:24:16: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
<source>:29:10: error: binding reference of type 'const T&' to 'volatile T' discards qualifiers
   29 |     *p = (volatile T)a;  // doesn't work for G++
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:30:10: error: passing 'volatile T' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
   30 |     *p = a;  // doesn't work for G++
      |          ^
<source>:24:16: note:   in call to 'constexpr T& T::operator=(const T&)'
   24 | typedef struct T {
      |
```

Why C++ standard wants to consider it as illegal, and what's the best practice to define the sturct to make it work?

Any suggestions would be appreciated :)

**[Edit]**
I follow the suggestion from *@Some programmer dude*

> For it to be possible the function need to be declared with the
> volatile qualifier itself: T& operator=(T const&) volatile;

```
typedef struct T {
    int val;

    T& operator=(const T &a) volatile {
        val = a.val;
        return const_cast<T&>(*this);
    }
} T;

void test(volatile T*p, T a) {
    *p = (volatile T)a;  // doesn't work for G++
    *p = a;  // doesn't work for G++
}
```

Error message by Clang 15 is

```
<source>:15:8: error: no viable overloaded '='
    *p = (volatile T)a;  // doesn't work for G++
    ~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:8:8: note: candidate function not viable: 1st argument ('volatile T') would lose volatile qualifier
    T& operator=(const T &a) volatile {
       ^
```

Not sure if misunderstood something.

Comment: What are you planning to do with `volatile` anyway?

Comment: volatile only makes sense for writing to and from memory mapped devices. It has nothing to do with thread safety. Read up on volatile here : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv. Specially this part : *Any attempt to refer to a volatile object through a glvalue of non-volatile type (e.g. through a reference or pointer to non-volatile type) results in undefined behavior.*

Comment: @PepijnKramer  Indeed.  [Why does the belief that `volatile` works for multithreaded access persist](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.programming.threads/c/OZeX2EpcN9U/m/VdHJcE62LL0J)?  It's **wrong**.  `volatile` provides **zero** guarantees with respect to atomicity or visibility in other threads.

Comment: Yes indeed, even writing to a volatile variable is not threadafe (if the write cannot be done in one instruction). @JYT So really the question is not about this error but WHAT are you trying to solve, there are probably much better ways of doing that.

Comment: Hi @Pepijn Kramer, it's a library to allow programmers write code which can compile on x86. The code is for another real platform which uses a customized compiler. The real platform does not have multithreads, RTOS. But it does have special memory.

Comment: @JYT So the compilation to x86 is to be able to simulate the real device then? 
Then I understand the use of volatile :)  I think that instead of `*p = (volatile T)a;`, `*p = a;` is enought. Casting to volatile AFAIK is not needed. (Disclaimer I don't have much embedded C++ experience though, just going by what I think I know of C++ after more then 30 years of working with it)

Comment: Hi @Pepijn Kramer, thanks you. Yes, the current workaround is to disallow the coding style (the customized compiler is actually a C++ dialect). Just trying to support it if possible, but it's also fine if there is no way to do it, because *p = a; works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Building with Clang gives a better error message](https://godbolt.org/z/KnTo5qr5M), where it says

> candidate function (the implicit copy assignment operator) not viable: 'this' argument has type 'volatile T', but method is not marked volatile

What happens is that the C++ compiler creates an implicit assignment operator, it will be declared as

```
T& operator=(T const&);
```

Because the object you assign to is qualified with `volatile` the compiler-generated assignment operator can't be used. For it to be possible the function need to be declared with the `volatile` qualifier itself:

```
T& operator=(T const&) volatile;
```

---

This is similar to `const` qualified objects and functions. Member functions needs the `const` qualifier to be called on `const` objects.

---

Now as for how to solve this conundrum: First you have to decide if you really need `volatile`. Chances are that you *don't*. Then just remove its use, and the problem will be automatically solved.

Then you also have to think about the build process itself. Is the code supposed to be C Code, or C++ code? It can't really be both at the same time. While the header-file could be included for both languages, the source code itself can only be one or the other.